# How to define a JSON-compatible parameter to avoid error "Index signature is missing"?

Tags: json, typescript

I've got a function defined as:

```
export function useSubmitHandler(url: string, data: Json): [FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>, boolean] {}
```

Where `Json` is:

```
type JsonPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null | undefined
interface JsonMap extends Record<string, JsonPrimitive | JsonArray | JsonMap> {}
interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonPrimitive | JsonArray | JsonMap> {}
export type Json = JsonPrimitive | JsonMap | JsonArray
```

If I try to call it with an arbitrary interface though, I get an error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Fee' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Json'.   
Type 'Fee' is not assignable to type 'JsonMap'.     
Index signature is missing in type 'Fee'
```

[image]

But if I call it with that same object but spread like `{...store.data}` then the error goes away.

How can I type `useSubmitHandler` properly so that it will accept any object that is JSON stringifyable?

I think the `Json` type is correct, but it needs something more to allow passing arbitrary types into the function.

---

`Fee` is:

```
interface Fee {
    id: number|null;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    amount: string;
    default: number;
    company_id: number;
    deleted_at?: any;
    active: number;
    fee_or_discount: string;
}
```

Of course, I'd like this to work with any type.

Comment: What does type `Fee` look like?

Comment: JSON is a text format. The only type compatible with JSON is `string | undefined | null`

Comment: @Evert I added the definition of `Fee` to the question. The function should accept any type that can be converted to JSON though.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know JSON is a string, but when people say "JSON" what they generally mean is a plain old JS object, not the text representation. We're talking about `JSON.stringify` here, not `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @mpen Well "people" are wrong, and the more often their wrong, the more difficult it is to discuss the problems of serialization to and from the format. When you say JSON and mean object, you make it that much more likely for people to write `JSON.parse(jsonObject)` when `jsonObject` is already an object, and we get the 1552nd question about "Unknown token 'o'  ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1: Redefine `Json` type

```
type JsonPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null;
type JsonMap = {
    [key: string]: JsonPrimitive | JsonMap | JsonArray;
}
type JsonArray = Array<JsonPrimitive | JsonMap | JsonArray>;
type Json = JsonPrimitive | JsonMap | JsonArray;
```

### Option 2: Add an index signature to the `Fee` interface

```
interface Fee {
    [property: string]: any;
    id: number|null;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    amount: string;
    default: number;
    company_id: number;
    deleted_at?: any;
    active: number;
    fee_or_discount: string;
}
```

### Option 3: Add an inline type assertion for the index signature, such as:

```
useSubmitHandler(Router.route('fees.store')!, store.data as {[property: string]: any})
```

### See also

TypeScript GitHub issue [**Please provide a `json` basic type #1897**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897)

Comment: First solution seems to work. Not sure why it behaves differently than the `extends` solution, but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to handle this is to wrap `store.data` in a function which applies an index signature.

```
const indexed = <T extends {}>(obj: T): T & {[key: string]: never} => obj;
```

This function returns the same object that it was given but adds additional typescript information.  We keep all of the values of the previously known type `T` intact, but add an index signature `{[key: string]: never}` which tells typescript that any keys other than those in the type cannot be anything other than undefined.

You can call your handler like this

```
useSubmitHandler(url, indexed(store.data))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYAUBOBLAth4GBu0AvFHMJkgOZQA%20USArlgEYRq1TMIIA2EAhkg6MePDgyQATCADMMSCJICwAKHnA2M-gGNo8ZAFl%20YKBAAeGqXCgAlCNoRpJAHjIVKAGliJUmHHkIOfSQAQTQ0fhAgnyMwAD4oAG8AX1V1TR09HzCIqPNLSWscyOdg9GxcAmg6YOKompjjBJTVczBHYChQSG9kKBIyv0rAhsNjaOQ61WmVNo6oGQltPD6GOAgAZQZmfwAJQUk%20NAAKBjQeAC5ScnlPKEl%20YH4r4IBKJNSVNKQNNC1dKAAMQg0ESqigEKgGEkV0YLDYNBEPAA3ODIUh%20FgIFc3LdUSpIV1wNjru58YTMQgJMAcTcqOTIdItAweDT6ExWGgGRCHFgwIIQAB9aGwjlsbn3CB8DSSQWPAD8VwFEp0ARJcM5EpkIMFjkFkgwcAc1NpZNUn1U0m0PH4aGgDiQZCgWBAwJJbvxqgdTvk0jMin6UGcABVTBYIFYPnFjghmAArK7B16JqAAMiSAG0ANYQECm24AXVhEEIaGS-QSsbjnpUa022z2ByOxwA5C2vL7zIpji63a9XjNvZ1O-7JG7AyPu72Qa8a0OoJTqROpF2xyCAHSLn7IqAAel3uKog%20QTtVVWXfsUbs3yyqO-3GrYx8dnUQWOAAAtbhfV9e3xBPzxPddwUUsgA)

The other option is to change your definition of `Json` such that it doesn't have the index signature, which comes from using `Record`. But I'm assuming that would be less desirable since (I think) you would have to broaden what's allowed.